# Nomachine 4 for X forwarding

Tags: remote-desktop, nomachine

I have been using nomachine nx client to connect from my mac to an ubuntu server for a while now and it has been a great experience. The most useful feature for me was the option to open up just one application on the remote machine, instead of a full remote desktop connection. I used to to open a terminal on the remote machine. Basically it was a much faster, much better replacement for ssh -X.

All was great until I upgraded to the new version - nomachine 4. In this version I can not find that option. I have to run a full remote desktop session, which slows things down and is also much less convenient for my work.

Was this option removed from the client? Or is it hiding somewhere in there and I just can't find it?

Answer (score 1):

NoMachine 4 (free) does not replace NX Free Edition which is what you were probably using before. You will need the Workstation if you want run a custom (virtual desktop) session, i.e. rootless.

The following article explains more about this:

Differences between NoMachine (free) and NoMachine Workstation
https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00702